# The ring $R = F[X]/(X^2)$, and $(X^2)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $F[X]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $F$ and let $R = F[X]/(X^2)$,
and consider the ideal $(X) = (X)/(X^2)$

why the ideal $(X)^2 = 0$ in this ring?

thanks your help

Comment: I denote by $Y = [X]$ the class of $X$ in $F[X]/(X^2)$. Do you want to know why $(Y^2)=0$ or why $(Y)^2 = 0$?

Comment: Yes I want to know why (X)^2=0?

Comment: @Temo It is unclear where your problems lies. Do you want to know why $X^2 = 0$ in the quotient ring or is your problem with understanding why $(X)^2 = (X^2)$ (in the quotient ring, although this is true in general).

Comment: I want understand why the ideal X bar square equal zero X^2=0 in this ring ?

Comment: Do you understand why $(X)^2 = (X^2)$?

Comment: No understand this.

Comment: Remember, when they say $(X)^2 = 0$, they actually mean $(X)^2 \equiv 0 \mod (X^2)$, if that makes sense

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 2):

That is the definition of a quotient ring.

Namely in $R/I$, the elements $0$ and $i$ (for $i \in I$) both belong to the coset $I$.

Comment: Thank you .. I want to know why the ideal (X)^2=0

Answer (score 0):

In general, suppose you have a ring $R$ and ideals $I = (r_1, \dots, r_n)$ and $J = (s_1, \dots, s_m)$ of $R$. Then $IJ = (r_i s_j \mid i=1,\dots,n; j =1,\dots,m)$, i.e., the product ideal is generated by the pairwise product of the generators. This can be proven rather straightforwardly using the definition of an ideal given by generators.

Conceptually, a quotient ring $R/I$ can be thought of as 'the ring $R$ with the additional property that all elements in $I$ are equal to $0$'. Using this idea, you can immediately say that $X^2 = 0$ in $F[X]/(X^2)$: it is because $X^2 \in (X^2)$. Of course, formally you have to *define* the quotient ring $R/I$ and *define* a homomorpism $R \to R/I$ and only then can you prove that the image of every element of $I$ under that map is $0$. Again, the proof is straightforward using the definition.

In your case, this means that the ideal $(\overline X)^2$ of the quotient ring $F[X]/(X^2)$ is equal to $({\overline X}^2)$. Since ${\overline X}^2 = \overline{X^2} = 0$, this means that $(\overline X)^2 = (0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help but not inderstand why $X⎯⎯⎯⎯2=X2⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯=0$ Why equal zero in this ring

Comment: So, which of the two equalities ${\bar X}^2 = \overline {X^2}$ and $\overline {X^2} = 0$ do you not understand?

Comment: I do not understand why $X2⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯=0$.

Comment: Allright then, do you know the definition of a quotient ring $R/I$?

Comment: Yes I know the definition

Comment: Then, just write down the _definition_ of $\overline {X^2}$ and ${\bar 0}$. Those are the two that you have to show are equal; and the reason they are is going to be that $X^2 \in (X^2)$. I've updated my answer with the general idea: in $R/I$ every element of $I$ (or rather: the residue class of every element of $I$) is equal to $0$. You may find it easier to prove the general statement, because then there is no superfluous information.

Comment: Yes, Thank for your help.